# Multiple twitter Bootstrap Carousel control with class

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, class

I'm trying to setup multiple twitter bootstrap carousels on one page, but I don't want to use different IDs, as later I will be creating these dynamically. My issue is that by pressing buttons in first carousel I control all of them. I can't figure out how to address the elements correctly. How can I set up this code so that I can control each carousel separately, by using class and not ID?

jsfidle:
http://jsfiddle.net/RobRalph/shk63x3g/1/

HTML:

```
<body>

<!-- 1st carousel test -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
         <div class="carousel slide" data-interval="false">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="backview"></div>
                <ol class="carousel-indicators" >
                    <li data-target = ".carousel" data-slide-to = "0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target = ".carousel" data-slide-to = "1"></li>
                    <li data-target = ".carousel" data-slide-to = "2"></li>
                </ol>

                <!-- carousel first page -->
                <div class="item active">
                    <div class = "headeritem">
                    </div>
                    <div class = "bodyitem">
                    </div>

                    <div class = "carousel-caption">
                        <h3>1</h3>
                        <p>Lorum ipsum</p>

                    </div>


                </div>

                <!-- carousel second page -->
                <div class="item">
                    <div class = "headeritem">
                    </div>
                    <div class = "bodyitem">
                    </div>

                    <div class = "carousel-caption">
                        <h3>2</h3>
                        <p>Lorum ipsum</p>
                    </div>  
                </div>

                <!-- carousel third page -->
                <div class="item">
                    <div class = "headeritem">
                    </div>
                    <div class = "bodyitem">
                    </div>

                    <div class = "carousel-caption">
                        <h3>3</h3>
                        <p>Lorum ipsum</p>
                    </div>  
                </div>
            </div>

            <a class = "carousel-control left" href = ".carousel" data-slide = "prev">
            <span class = "icon-prev"></span>
            </a>
            <a class = "carousel-control right" href = ".carousel" data-slide = "next">
            <span class = "icon-next"></span>
            </a>


         </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

 <!-- 2nd carousel test -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
         <div class="carousel slide" data-interval="false">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="backview"></div>
                <ol class="carousel-indicators" >
                    <li data-target = ".carousel" data-slide-to = "0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target = ".carousel" data-slide-to = "1"></li>
                    <li data-target = ".carousel" data-slide-to = "2"></li>

                </ol>

                <!-- carousel first page -->

                <div class="item active">

                    <div class = "headeritem">
                    </div>
                    <div class = "bodyitem">
                    </div>


                    <div class = "carousel-caption">
                        <h3>1</h3>
                        <p>Lorum ipsum</p>

                    </div>


                </div>

                <!-- carousel second page -->
                <div class="item">
                    <div class = "headeritem">
                    </div>
                    <div class = "bodyitem">
                    </div>

                    <div class = "carousel-caption">
                        <h3>2</h3>
                        <p>Lorum ipsum</p>
                    </div>  
                </div>

                <!-- carousel third page -->
                <div class="item">
                    <div class = "headeritem">
                    </div>
                    <div class = "bodyitem">
                    </div>

                    <div class = "carousel-caption">
                        <h3>3</h3>
                        <p>Lorum ipsum</p>
                    </div>  
                </div>
            </div>

            <a class = "carousel-control left" href = ".carousel" data-slide = "prev">
            <span class = "icon-prev"></span>
            </a>
            <a class = "carousel-control right" href = ".carousel" data-slide = "next">
            <span class = "icon-next"></span>
            </a>
         </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Extra CSS:

```
.backview {
position:absolute;
top:0;
z-index:-99;
height:100%;
width:100%;

background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) ), url('https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpa1/v/t1.0-9/p480x480/10408976_1175768429116191_8145612220139098697_n.jpg?oh=45022b3bbf32769af5bf339f40cb2cb1&oe=55F527C3') no-repeat center center;
background-size:cover;

}


.headeritem {
    height:80px;    

}

.bodyitem {
    height:140px;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are going to need to use different IDs, when you are create them dynamically you should also assign them distinct IDs.

Here is a working Bootply demo with two carousels: http://www.bootply.com/04KMcAK0w4

You will need to use the ID in two locations.

On the carousel indicators (bullets) as the value of data attribute called **data-target**:

```
<li data-target="#myCarousel1" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
```

And on the forward and back buttons as the value of the href:

```
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel1" data-slide="prev">
```

Comment: si it's not possible with Class, unless I modify bootstrap.js?
I was afraid that it will come to the IDs, I guess I will have to look around how to add the specific IDs dynamically, shouldn't be too bad